# How is $ \left(1-\frac{p^2}{2mE}\right)^{3N/2-2} =\; \exp\left(-\frac{3N}{2}\frac{p^2}{2mE}\right)\;?$

Tags: statistical-mechanics

How is 
$$ \left(1-\frac{p^2}{2mE}\right)^{3N/2-2} = \exp\left(-\frac{3N}{2}\frac{p^2}{2mE}\right)$$
(Karder, Statistical Physics of Particles, Page 107)

in the large $E$ limit. Here $N$ is particle, of the order of $10^{23}$, $E$ is the total energy.
I roughly guess that it should be $\exp(-\frac{p^2}{2m})$ since both $N$ and $E$ can be treated as infinitely large.

---

Update: a hint to solution is provided in the comments.

Comment: because $(1+x/n)^n\approx e^x$? (you need to identify what is $x$ and what is $n$ in to your formula)

Comment: Thank you. I think need to assume $\frac{3N}{2}\frac{p^2}{2mE}$ as roughly a constant when $N$ and $E$ are infinite. Is this correct?

Comment: you can analyze this for every function check here [link] (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-2-applications-of-differentiation/part-a-approximation-and-curve-sketching/session-24-examples-of-linear-approximation/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses24b.pdf)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Very good questions. I have here a ideal gas model. So the answers to your questions are all positive I think. Thank you!

Comment: At Stack Exchange, we signify questions as "solved" by [accepting an answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), rather than modifying the title.

Comment: @KyleKanos Sorry, the situation is that the answers are in the comments. The answer provided below is not the best one. I will update my question to inform others if interested to look at the comment.

Comment: Comments are temporary as well around here. It's possible that at some point in the future they will be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a comment needs 50 reputation, and I got only 46 now. So I write my opinion here.
I have read the textbook, the original formula is
$$p(\vec{p_1})=(1-{{\vec{p_1}^2}\over {2mE}})^{3N/2-2}\cdots\cdots$$

So $\vec{p_1}$ is the momentum of only one particle in the ensemble. Considering the system has very large $N$, that is only a tiny proportion of total $E$, which makes the ${{\vec{p_1}^2}\over {2mE}}$ term approaches 0.

Then with the above comments of other guys, you can get the results. Here I think $3N/2$ makes no difference with $3N/2-2$ because $N$ is large

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approximations
$$1+x \simeq e^x$$ and 
$$(1+rx)  \simeq (1+x)^r$$
You can obtain 
$$(1+(-p^2/2mE))^{3N/2-2}$$ which can be approximated in the $N\gg1$ limit as $$(1+(-p^2/2mE))^{3N/2}$$ which is approximately equal to$$(1+\frac{3N}{2}(-p^2/2mE))\rightarrow \exp [1 + (-p^2/2mE)]^\frac{3N}{2}$$ by using the first foruma above. Here $\frac{3N}{2}$ is considered as a constant number much greater than 1, probably the ${3N/2-2}$ is the correction.

Comment: The approximation requires that x to be very small. I have an ideal gas model here, since the Boltzmann constant is very small, N/E will be large. So the last step might be problematic.